# DiD vs Repeated meausres ANOVA vs ANCOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, difference-in-difference, ancova

I am learning statistical analyses for experimental and quasi-experimental studies.

From my class and by searching answers here and asking ChatGPT, I have some preliminary understandings of Difference-in-Difference analysis, repeated measures ANOVA, and ANCOVA.

Please correct me if I'm wrong: It seems both DiD and repeated measures ANOVA used for analyzing changes of scores, but ANCOVA used specifically for controlling baseline score.

For experimental studies, such randomized clinical trial and nonrandomized clinical trials, which analysis is most appropriate to use? why?

For quasi-experimental studies, such as natural experiment, which one is most appropriate to use? why?

I found some answers (like: [Difference in Difference vs repeated measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194888/difference-in-difference-vs-repeated-measures)) indicating that mathematically speaking, DiD and repeated measures ANOVA are actually identical. Is this correct? If so, can I use DiD in clinical trials instead of repeated measures ANOVA and ANCOVA? (Or, can I use repeated measures ANOVA for quasi-experimental studies?)

Thank you for shedding light on my questions.